# Matlab output matrix to file with a reasonable format

Tags: python, matlab, string-formatting

I am writing the representation of an object to file. Its follows this simple format

```
<key>:<value>\n
```

Now I have multiple matrices to output, but the standard-way looks very ugly

```
f = open('somefile', 'w+t');
fprintf(f,'size:');
fprintf(f,'%+.4f\n', someObject.size);
```

But this will just result in an unreadble file like this

```
size: 5.1234
3.1234
2.5421
232332
```

And so on for hundreds of lines. If I do this in python/numpy `( f.write("size: " + str(someObject.size) + "\n")` I get something readable like

```
size:[[5.1234 3.1234 2.5421 232322]
[5.1234 3.1234 2.5421 232322]....
```

It preserves the shape and aligns it properly. How do I do this with matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split the `fprintf` command. Use an auxilary function:

```
function numpy_like_fprintf(fid, format_single_element, values)
fprintf(fid, '[');
fprintf(fid, [' ',format_single_element], values);
fprintf(fid, ' ]\n');
```

Now you can

```
numpy_like_fprintf(f, '%+.4f', someObject.size);
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [`num2str`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html)
 to convert the array to string, much like python's `str()`.
Note that you can format the way numbers are converted to strings in `num2str`